# Xcode, is it possible to intercept and change code on build without updating the file? If so, how?

Tags: xcode, build, scripting, compilation

I need a way to intercept the code before it goes into the compiler, change it, AND have it remain the same in the file / in Xcode afterwards.

I thought build scripts were a sort of stream interception but that doesn't seem to be the case. Another method might be to run a script both before and after build.  Are there any implications with this I should be aware of?

**----- EDIT -----**

Why?  I have an idea for an auto-logging system based on a certain comment syntax.  I want to be able, on build, to parse a certain string and replace it with a logging function but have the code remain unchanged.  Is it possible?

**----- UPDATE -----**

It seems a custom compiler might be the way forward, or at least a plugin that wraps current LLVM clang.  I've been investigating this.  Here's a related question for those interested: [Xcode custom compiler which wraps and does a passthru to clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516725/)

Comment: Why don't you better describe what you are actually trying to accomplish. Then maybe someone can offer a suggestion.

Comment: Looks like you are longing for C preprocessor (cpp - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) ;)

Comment: That would be great if you could match `//` but I don't think you can.  The reason for the idea to have (certain) comments be logs is to reduce redundancy and to have lots of logging without creating clutter in the code. So I guess the commenting matching part is the key bit.

Comment: Hey @HariKaramSingh, it's been a while but did you manage to accomplish that? :) Any tips?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. Let me know if you do! It's been a few iterations of Xcode.....

Answer (score 2):

If by "on build" you mean before actually compiling the code, that means you need to open Xcode every time you want to run your script. I don't believe there is a way to do this. However, you CAN use Automator to receive a string before running the code, but you would need to use Automator to build the app, which is limiting. Another method would be to make 2 classes in your app: a pre-run class and a main class. The pre-run class will prompt the user or read a file (or something like that) to get the string, and run the main class in a special way depending on the string.

**Edit: response to comment**

I don't know how to do this in Objective-C, but you can always rename your main file to main.mm (.mm files contain both C++ and Objective-C code) and add C++ code to it. However, this is using the Console:

```
using namespace std // all  (this line is optional)
string s = ""; //      this
cin >> s; //           is C++  (if you omitted the optional line above, the correct code is std::cin >> s;
MainClass mc = //constructor for your "main class" here in Objective-C
if(s == someCertainString){ //hypothetical string and C++ condition checking for a C++ string
    [mc doThisACertainWay:];
}else if(s == someOtherString){ // again, hypothetical string that you need to declare
    [mc doThisADifferentWay];
}
```

I'm not on a PC now so I can't check code, but you can search for how to read and write to files in C++ and Obj-C. The only hint I can give right now is that you need `#include <iostream>` at the beginning if you use C++ to read/write the file.

If you don't want to use the console (which is normal if you wan to publish this) you can also make a dialog. In this example, you don't need C++ so you don't rename the main file. Make a new window (referred to as `theDialog` from now on) that is visible at start and make sure that your main graphical interface does NOT show up startup. Add a text field to `theDialog` and give it a name (in this example, `tf`). Add a label to tell the user what to put in the text field. Add a button and link it to an action. In this action, put the following code:

```
MainClass mc = // constructor here
NSString *str = [self.tf stringValue];
if([str equalsString:someString]){ // hypothetical string and possible error in the condition checking, I'm new to Obj-C
    [mc doThisInACertainWay];
} else {
    [mc doThisInADifferentWay];
}
```

Comment: "The pre-run class will prompt the user or read a file (or something like that) to get the string, and run the main class in a special way"  - How would one do this?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean.  Thanks for taking the time to write it out, but it isn't really what I'm after...

Comment: So what exactly are you after?

Comment: See the question, under "--EDIT--".  I want to be able to find say `//! Some logging information` and replace it with `NSLog(@"Some logging information")` but only for the compiler, not for the person coding who will just always see `//! Some logging information`