# Xcode custom compiler which wraps and does a passthru to clang

Tags: xcode, bash, compiler-construction, xcode5

I'm trying to implement a certain pre-compilation effect on objective-C code ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068830/)). I've managed to get a custom compiler in place in Xcode 5 following [these helpful instructions](http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/add-custom-compiler-to-xcode/). However my passthru attempt to clang results in an error:

My custom compiler's executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
clang "$@"
```

Error message:

```
While building module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/Club15CC/Google Drive/Code/Frogger/Frogger/Frogger-Prefix.pch:14:
...
In file included from  
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:13:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h:33:1: 
error: use of empty enum
};
^
/Users/Club15CC/Google Drive/Code/Frogger/Frogger/Frogger-Prefix.pch:14:13: fatal error: could not build module 'UIKit'
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
Command /usr/bin/frogger failed with exit code 1
```

Note the executable is called `frogger` and the test Xcode project `Frogger`.

It builds fine with the default compiler. Does the enum error imply some flag isn't being passed through?  Does bash have a limit to the size of `$@`?  The compiler invoking string is rather long and perhaps is being truncated?

Thanks for any help...

---- UPDATE ----

It seems as though it's passing the wrong "minimum version" flag to the custom compiler:  The normal LLVM compiler has this flag: `-mios-simulator-version-min=7.0` while my custom one is getting this flag: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6` - which is the cause of the `UIDevice` error.  The correct flags are handled inside of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/Native Build System.xcspec` and the equivalent one for iOS as opposed to simulator.  It seems somehow my custom compilers not picking up these specs.  I'm in over my head here!

Comment: Why did you need to configure a custom compiler?  I post-process a `flex` file using a python script and was able to set that up using an Xcode Build Rule.  I think you can do that same thing by giving your special source files a special extension and then configuring the Build Rules to use your script to build them.

Comment: Ideally, I want it to work for all .m and .mm files without needing the implementor to do anything special other than install a plugin.  More details about the "why" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068830/xcode-is-it-possible-to-intercept-and-change-code-on-build-without-updating-the

Comment: What does this issue have to do with bash?

Comment: Because bash might be used to run some preprocessing script and then pipe the output through clang. Turns out this isn't really a suitable solution though.